# How to get the 10 highest count in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the 10 highest values of 'product_id' that the many number of users are rated in SQL. But my code is not working.

Here is my SQL code.

```
select top(10) product_id from request_list order by product_id DESC;
```

Here are some data of 'request_list' table in database.

1. 1 akar.user@com
2. 1 abc.user@com
3. 10 pqr.user@com
4. 10 ijk.user@com
5. 10 akar.user@com

According to the above data product_id = 10 should be got as the first value, since it is the highest value that the many number of users are rated.

Comment: Is your Product ID just the number or the whole string?

Comment: @shree.pat18 it is a string.

Comment: Ok, please add the tag for whichever DBMS you are using.

Comment: Give the table deatail structure and expected output as tabular format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the top 10 most frequently appearing products

```
select top 10 product_id, count(*)
from request_list
group by product_id
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM request_list ORDER BY product_id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax says it is `Sql Server` not `Mysql`. Try this.

```
SELECT TOP(10) product_id
FROM   request_list
ORDER  BY cast(LEFT(product_id, Charindex(' ', product_id)) as Int) DESC
```